# Switch account in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, logout

How can I logout from PhpStorm? I even tried to uninstall it and remove everything related to JetBrains, but still no luck...

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do you want to disassociate your license with the installed version of PhpStorm? I'm on Windows and it's Help > Register... > Remove License

Comment: There it is!

Im surprised this wasnt easier to find, thanks a bunch!

/Tarre

Comment: Same is the case for Macs. Just in case, someone is searching